# Number of render slots

Tags: rendering, uv-image-editor

In this old video Blender has 10 render slots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfMJ9NDpXAI

However, in my new 2.78 version, I see only 8 render slots. Is there a way to set the total number of slots? Actually, I would like to have more than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During [this](https://developer.blender.org/rB57101c4fd26a85f4994d4d4d3f433c37f95367d0) commit a constant named `IMA_MAX_RENDER_SLOT` was introduced and set to 8.

You'd have to change the line

```
#define IMA_MAX_RENDER_SLOT     8
```

in [source/blender/makesdna/DNA_image_types.h](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/makesdna/DNA_image_types.h$200) to something else and re-compile to change the number of slots.

Comment: Oh, and probably even this would not be enough, because the number 8 is hardcoded twice for some reason in this file, and only the comments say that this 8 stands for IMA_MAX_RENDER_SLOT. I guess I'll live with eight slots. Anyway, thank you for digging in the source code!

Comment: You can increase the number of slots, it just means building your own copy of blender, my builds of blender have had 10 slots for the last 6 years. The three places in DNA_image_types.h are all you need to change. A quick test shows that 30 slots appears to still work right.