# How to Add Render Slots in Blender?

Tags: rendering

I heard somewhere that it's possible to determine the number of render slots available in 2.8 but I can't seem to find the option to change it from 8....

Comment: Please elaborate on what kind of workflow you are doing.  Render slots or view layers? It would help to understand what you want to do and what you are doing currently. please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information.

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65912/number-of-render-slots If this is still the case, 8 slots has been hardcoded into Blender and cannot be changed unless you modify the source code and recompile it all. You can also try looking into other BlenderBuilds by the community here https://blender.community/c/graphicall/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done uder the Image tab in the Side Bar of the Render View / Image Editor

[image]